# Variable not being readable in the current context, while it is in the current context

Tags: .net, visual-studio

The debugger is throwing this error:

```
error CS0103: The name "docXml" does not exists in the current context
```

But the 'docXml' variable is present in the current context, like below:

[image]

There isn't a similar at the class:

[image]

Event the Exception occured after trying to access docXml is not available:

[image]

Comment: Are you having a compile-time error or a run-time error?

Comment: No, it is everything right!

Comment: It's a serious question. How are you getting a compiler error at runtime? Where is this code from-- is it some type of [JIT](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/jit-just-in-time-compiler/)ed module, e.g. a view or a csx? What sort of project is it?

Comment: Uhm... it is a simple service, that is getting some XML from the FileSystem and processing it.

Comment: @JohnWu Well , thank you very much for your help!! I just found what was happening... The Release was selected and I should be debugging in Debug Compiler Mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was being ran under **Release Mode**.

In order to avoid these errors, I should switch it to **Debug Mode**.